# Как получить данные из локального файла js?

Tags: vue.js

есть js файл в нем данные в виде:

```
export const products = [
  {
    "name": "mobile1",
    "type": "big",
    "color": "green",
  },
  {
    "name": "mobile2",
    "type": "small",
    "color": "blue",
  }
]
```

как получить products в компоненте?

Comment: `import { products } from '../localfile.js';`  ?

Comment: "export 'products' was not found in '../api/products'


import { products }  from '../api/products'
export default {
    mounted() {
        console.log(products)
    }
}